# How to specify the return value of a function based on the value of a parameter

Tags: typescript

I have something like the following:

```
function myFunctionBuilder(/* Parameters Irrelevant to MWE */) {
   return function (argument: Targument): [ -1 | 0 | 1, Targument ] {
    // ...
   }
}
```

and I would like to add `parameter1` to `myFunctionBuilder` which would allow one to specify a number to be returned in place of -1 | 0 | 1, under certain conditions, and I wondered if it's possible to add this user-specified value in the return type? The following is incorrect, but (hopefully!) illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function myFunctionBuilder(parameter1: number, /* Parameters Irrelevant to MWE */) {
   return function (argument: Targument): [ -1 | 0 | 1 | parameter1, Targument ] {
    // ...
   }
}
```

Is this possible, or do I just have to broaden the return type to any number? i.e.:

```
function myFunctionBuilder(parameter1: number, /* Parameters Irrelevant to MWE */) {
   return function (argument: Targument): [ number, Targument ] {
    // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic can be thought of as a way to "store" the type of a parameter that was given:

```
function myFunctionBuilder<Parameter1 extends number>(parameter1: Parameter1, /* Parameters Irrelevant to MWE */) {
   return function (argument: Targument): [ -1 | 0 | 1 | Parameter1, Targument ] {
    // ...
   }
}
```

`extends number` is a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints). It means that `parameter1` must be a number.

Comment: I didn't realize a generic would extract the actual value, like this; thank you for taking the time to reply and helping me understand!

Comment: This is working; however, I get an error if I try to set a default value for `parameter1`: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Parameter1'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Parameter1', but 'Parameter1' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'." Any chance you could point me towards the relevant docs?

Comment: I think you're gonna have to cast the default value: `parameter1: Parameter1 = ?? as Parameter1`. Don't forget to also add the default type for the generic: `Parameter1 extends number = 0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me, but it's probably because, in my actual application, `parameter1` is a key in a destructured object: `{ parameter1 = NaN }: { parameter1: Parameter1 }` I searched for "casting" in the TS docs, but didn't get any hits, so I'll just set the default within the body of the function. Thanks again!